# JS function - rounding a 1 decimal place floating number up and down

Tags: javascript, math

I want to create a function that rounds a floating number up and down but only when there is 0.1 difference...

i.e.

```
3.9  = 4
3.8 = 3.8
4.1 = 4
4.2 = 4.2
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Paul, do you want to decide if the difference of two numbers is less than 0.1? What should be the input and the output of the function *exactly*?

Comment: `const customRound = (a) => (+Math.abs(Math.round(a) - a).toFixed(1) <= 0.1)?Math.round(a):a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```js
/* 
3.9  = 4
3.8 = 3.8
4.1 = 4
4.2 = 4.2
*/
const nums = [3.9, 3.8, 4.1, 4.2, 4.01]
const rounded = nums.map(num => 
  Math.abs(+(Math.round(num) - num).toFixed(1)) == .1 ? Math.round(num) : num
)
console.log(rounded)
```

Comment: PS: I added 4.01 - should that also just be passed?